# Existence of smooth, but cannot represented by series of fractional power

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We know that there are functions that are smooth on the real line but not analytic($e^{-1/g^2}$). I am wondering if there exists a smooth function, which cannot be represented by fractional power series. By fractional power series, I mean a series $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{p_{n}}$, where $p_{n}$ are real numbers such that $p_{n+1}>p_{n}$ for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Also, this series must converge in some open ball.

To conclude, my question is, does there exists a function $f(x)$, that is infinitely differentiable on an interval but cannot be expressed by a convergent fractional power series(as defined above)?

Comment: Hint: the sum of a "fractional power series" is real-analytic

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich How about $e^{-1/g^2}$? It can be expressed as "fractional power series", but it is not real analytic.

Comment: It's not globally real-analytic. It's also not globally the almost-uniform sum of a fractional power series; it _is_ real-analytic on any open set where the series converges uniformly on compact subsets